# ActionScript 3 : Particle Collition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm working on my school assignment and i got stuck.
So, the idea is i want to make somehing like in this video, particle collision demonstration (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKqpOOgXLzE) but i cant find any tutorial for that. So i tried to find a tutorial that has similar concept with the video, the pong game. I found a tutorial with multiple ball colliding each other (https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/06/07/managing-multiple-balls-collisions-with-flash-as3-version/). and i tried to modify the code to make the ball hit the platform, but sadly it did nothing and i cant think of any other solution.

here's the code:

```
public class BallCollision extends MovieClip
{
    private var mcBallContainer:MovieClip;
    private var nNumBalls:Number = 15;
    
    private var mcBrickCOntainer:MovieClip;
    
    private var nStageWidth:Number = 200;
    private var nStageHeight:Number = 200;
    
    private var brick1: Brick;
    var score:Number = 0;
    
    public function BallCollision ( ) : void
    {
        mcBallContainer = new MovieClip ( ) ;
        mcBallContainer.x = 755;
        mcBallContainer.y = 408;
        stage.addChild(mcBallContainer);
        
        mcBrickCOntainer = new MovieClip();
        mcBrickCOntainer.x = 200;
        mcBrickCOntainer.y = 250;
        stage.addChild(mcBrickCOntainer);
        
        this.addEventListener ( Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler );
        
        for ( var i = 0; i < nNumBalls; i++ )
        {
            var mcBall:Ball = new Ball ( Math.floor ( ( Math.random() * 12 ) - 4 ), Math.floor ( ( Math.random() * 12 ) - 4 ) );
            mcBall.x = Math.random() * nStageWidth;
            mcBall.y = Math.random() * nStageHeight;
            mcBallContainer.addChild ( mcBall );
            
        brick1 = new Brick();
        brick1.x = 700;
        brick1.y = 350;
        mcBrickCOntainer.addChild(brick1);
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    private function enterFrameHandler ( E:Event ) : void
    {
        for ( var i = 0; i < mcBallContainer.numChildren; i++ )
        {
            var mcBall1:* = mcBallContainer.getChildAt( i );
            
            for ( var j = i + 1; j < mcBallContainer.numChildren; j++ )
            {
                var mcBall2:* = mcBallContainer.getChildAt( j );
                
                var nDistX:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.x - mcBall2.x );
                var nDistY:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.y - mcBall2.y );
                var nDistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( nDistX * nDistX + nDistY * nDistY );
                
                if ( nDistance < 20 )
                {
                    solveBalls ( mcBall1, mcBall2 );
                    score += 1;
                    trace(score);
                }
        
            }
        } 
        
        
        
        scoreCounter.text = String(score);
        //brickCalling();
        
        
    }
    
    /*public function brickCalling(){
        }*/
    
    private function solveBalls ( MCBallA:MovieClip, MCBallB:MovieClip) : void
    {
        var nX1:Number = MCBallA.x;
        var nY1:Number = MCBallA.y;
        var nDistX:Number = MCBallB.x - nX1;
        var nDistY:Number = MCBallB.y - nY1;
        
        var nDistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( nDistX * nDistX + nDistY * nDistY );
        var nRadiusA:Number = MCBallA.width/2;
        var nRadiusB:Number = MCBallB.width/2;
        //var nRadius:Number = 10;
        
        var nNormalX:Number = nDistX/nDistance;
        var nNormalY:Number = nDistY/nDistance;
        
        var nMidpointX:Number = ( nX1 + MCBallB.x )/2;
        var nMidpointY:Number = ( nY1 + MCBallB.y )/2;
        
        MCBallA.x = nMidpointX - nNormalX * nRadiusA;
        MCBallA.y = nMidpointY - nNormalY * nRadiusA;
        MCBallB.x = nMidpointX + nNormalX * nRadiusB;
        MCBallB.y = nMidpointY + nNormalY * nRadiusB;
        
        var nVector:Number = ( ( MCBallA.nSpeedX - MCBallB.nSpeedX ) * nNormalX )+ ( ( MCBallA.nSpeedY - MCBallB.nSpeedY ) * nNormalY );
        var nVelX:Number = nVector * nNormalX;
        var nVelY:Number = nVector * nNormalY;
        
        MCBallA.nSpeedX -= nVelX;
        MCBallA.nSpeedY -= nVelY;
        MCBallB.nSpeedX += nVelX;
        MCBallB.nSpeedY += nVelY;
    }
    
    
}
}
```

I hope someone can guide me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a physics engine, like box2D?

https://www.box2dflash.org

Comment: oh i dont know about this, thanks for your suggestion. ill try it